# make the image smaller while displaying in a table

Tags: html, image

how to display image in a small size in html

Suppose i am displaying the images in this way ---

```
<td>
  <a href="//your link//"><img src="//image url//"></a>
</td>
```

But the image is displaying so big, how can i control the image size and make it small.

Answer (score 1):

Set `height` and `width` attributes of `img` tag

```
<img height="50px" width="50px" src="//image url//">
```

Answer (score 1):

As in this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/szz81p3h/) adding the `width` attribute  will make it smaller, the value can be set in pixels or percentage

```
<img src="//placehold.it/1000x300?text=largeImage" width="100%">
```

or in `pixels` [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/chuode83/3/)

```
<img src="//placehold.it/1000x300?text=largeImage" width="300">
```

Note that same thing can be set for `height` value

Answer (score -1):

Set the height and width simply

```
<img height="120px" width="120px" src="{{ data.image_url }}">
```

But i belive the best practise will be also to set it like if it is `defined` than it should show else a `default` action

```
    <td>
   {% if data.image_url is defined %}
    <img height="120px" width="120px" src="{{ data.image_url }}"></a> 
   {% else %} 
   </td>{% endif %}
```

Comment: `{% if data.image_url is defined %}` and `{% endif %}` are HTML code?